# Matlab input Excel file(raw data) on A-path but output Result file on B-path (have raw data)

Tags: excel, matlab, input, io

I am working with raw data of magnetic fields from a satellite.

I want to input raw data from my folder on the desktop (here is my Path-A)
and to output data to desktop (here is my Path-B) as Excel. Could anybody help thanks!

Here is my raw data and code link:

```
(raw data size: 11MB,Elapsed time is 25.298137 seconds.)
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1U-u9Q1mjU8cUFESkFYTnd3T2s

[image: screenshoot here:]

Comment: So `xlsread` and `xlswrite`?

Answer (score -1):

tic;

[num,txt,raw]=xlsread('MTHD1001.xlsx');

length=size(num);

a=length(1);

Bx=num(1:a);

By=num(a+1:a+a);

Bz=num(a+a+1:a+a+a);

B=sqrt(Bx.*Bx+By.*By+Bz.*Bz);

format long e

M=max(B);

m=min(B);

total=[txt(1) a m M];

fprintf('Maximum of B is %e nano Tesla\n',M);

fprintf('minimum of B is %e nano Tesla\n',m);

figure,plot(B);

xlswrite('Bddata.xlsx',total,1,'A1');

toc;